# Error: Index exceeds matrix dimension in simulating AR process

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a data file of size 256 rows. I want to fit the data to a second order AR(2) process and then simulate the process after fitting. I have the following code but it returns error **Index exceeds matrix dimensions.**

```
whos y1
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  y1        1x1              1712  cell
```

whos coeff

```
is  1x3                24  double
```

Please help in resolving the error. Also, how do I check with a plot that the original data and the fitted data are almost same and get the error ?

```
load('b1.dat');
y1=b1(:);

if ~iscell(y1); y1 = {y1}; end

model = ar(y1, 2, 'ls');



coeffs = model.a;
ar_coeff1=[coeff(2) coeff(3)]


%simulate
for i =3 : 256

   y1(i) = coeff(2) *y1(i-1) +coeff(3)*y1(i-2) ;  **% This line returns error**

end
```

Comment: Report the size of the offending matrices, for instance post results of `whos y1` and `whos coeff1`

Comment: Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  y1        1x1              1712  cell

Comment: And whos coeff1 returns  1x3                24  double

Comment: You mention in the comments below one answer that you adjusted something. Please make sure/confirm that the question (as well as the title title) stays up to date and contains all relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing operation, cell addition, and cell/double multiplication operations as posted are not allowed.

If `a` is a cell array (such as `y1`) generated as follows:

```
>> a={1:256}
a = 

    [1x256 double]

>> whos a
  Name      Size                    Bytes  Class

  a        1x1                      2108  cell array

Grand total is 257 elements using 2108 bytes
```

I cannot index into a(2) because it doesn't exist:

```
>> a(2)
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

I cannot add one cell and another as follows:

```
>> a(1)+a(1)
??? Function 'plus' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
```

and I cannot multiply a cell and type double as follows:

```
>> a*3
??? Function 'mtimes' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.

Error in ==> mtimes at 16
  builtin('mtimes', varargin{:});
```

As an example, the following is allowed:

```
for ii =3 : 256
   y1{1}(ii) = coeff(2) *y1{1}(ii-1) +coeff(3)*y1{1}(ii-2) ;  
end
```

Note also from the `ARFIT` demo file:

> % ... ARfit  contains modules for estimating parameters of AR
>   models from given  time series data; for checking the adequacy of
>   an estimated  AR model; ...

so check the `ARfit` documentation and demo.

**Edit:**

In general if `ydat` is the source data (in cell array format) and `ysim` is the result of a fit to the data (or modeling operation), then one can plot the residuals between the data and fit with `plot(ydat{1}-ysim{1})` and compute the RMS deviation as `sqrt(sum(ydat{1}-ysim{1}).^2)/length(ysim{1})`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I corrected the for loop but Now it throws the error Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Comment: Run `whos` again and make sure the inputs are as they were originally with `y1` a 1x1 cell and `coeff` a type double variable. With (for example) `y1 = {1:256}`, `coeff = [1:3]` the loop should work.

Comment: Why have you done y1{1}? What does the 1 index imply?  I commented off the not is cell command and just did plain for loop y1(ii) but used ar_coeff1(1) and ar_coeff2(2) instead and there is no error.But I did not understand so.

Comment: I have read the documentation and it estimates the parameteres using least square regression with QR decomposition. However, the values are different from this toolbox and if calculated from ar() method! What I do not understand is for 2 varaible model and order=2 why should there be 8 coeficients?

Comment: In the original form that you posted you were mixing double and cell data types, as explained in my answer. With your change you basically solved the problem yourself, in a different (an in fact simpler way). The 1 in `y1{1}` indexes into the first element of cell array `y1`, which in your case contained the data vector (of type double I presume). Since as you reported `coeff` is  a 1x3 double indexing as you did in the original post was ok (and you might be introducing an error with your new indexing).

Comment: Note also I removed my original suggestion on how to compute errors since it may be misleading if not incorrect for the AR methods you are exploring. I would apply the built-in methods available with the toolbox instead.

Comment: I found you RMSE method to  be intuitive rather than using the residuals from matlab since those commands give errors when I had to use predict().But then,this issue would form another question.Can I not use your method for error calculation with the correct indexing?

Comment: I'll place back those lines as a separate edit, but I'd have to do more research into the question. Intuitively though it seems correct.